# Smart cast to 'Type' is impossible, because 'variable' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: kotlin

And the Kotlin newbie asks, "why won't the following code compile?":

```
var left: Node? = null
    
fun show() {
    if (left != null) {
        queue.add(left) // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

> Smart cast to 'Node' is impossible, because 'left' is a mutable
> property that could have been changed by this time

I get that `left` is mutable variable, but I'm explicitly checking `left != null` and `left` is of type `Node` so why can't it be smart-casted to that type?

How can I fix this elegantly?

Comment: Somewhere in between a different thread could have changed the value to null again. I'm pretty sure answers on the other questions mention that as well.

Comment: You could use a [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) to add

Comment: thanks @nhaarman that makes sense, Whymarrh how can do that? I thought safe calls were only for objects not methods

Comment: Something like: `n.left?.let { queue.add(it) }` I think?

Comment: @iknow This help me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy-dS2SVoHk

Comment: @nhaarman does the "change" specifically talk about changing to "null" value ? or something else value other than current assigned value ?

Answer (score 515, accepted):

Between execution of `left != null` and `queue.add(left)` another thread could have changed the value of `left` to `null`.

To work around this you have several options. Here are some:

1. Use a local variable with smart cast:

   ```
    val node = left
    if (node != null) {
        queue.add(node)
    }
   ```
2. Use a [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) such as one of the following:

   ```
    left?.let { node -> queue.add(node) }
    left?.let { queue.add(it) }
    left?.let(queue::add)
   ```
3. Use the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) with [`return`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html) to [return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels) early from the enclosing function:

   ```
    queue.add(left ?: return)
   ```

   Note that `break` and `continue` can be used similarly for checks within loops.

Comment: 4. Think of a more functional solution to your problem that doesn't require mutable variables.

Comment: What is this n in n.left?

Comment: @sak It was an instance of a `Node` class defined in the original version of the question which had a more complicated code snippet with `n.left` instead of simply `left`. I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @mfulton26 Thanks for making it clear, but what if I have this error for 3 variables? e.g: "MyAsyncTask().execute(a1,a2,a3)" and here a1, a2, a3 all giving smart cast error.

Comment: @sak The same concepts apply. You can create a new `val` for each `var`, nest several `?.let` statements, or use several `?: return` statements depending on your function. e.g. `MyAsyncTask().execute(a1 ?: return, a2 ?: return, a3 ?: return)`. You can also try one of the solutions for a ["multiple variable let"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35513636/3255152).

Comment: @FARID, I wasn't trying to be a smart ass. Re-thinking your design to rely less on mutability is a valid approach to solve concurrency issues.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, apparently, I went far by calling you a name, sorry for that. But at some point, we have to use `mutable` consequently end up in a mess and looking for a proper solution. Every time I take a look at comments to see others' ideas on the solution while checking the answer. I just carried away for a moment by your answer and unnecessarily vent spleen on you ))

Comment: Will the first option be safe? I mean it will not create any NPE later right? @mfulton26. Because I will be making these changes in production environment.

Comment: Yes, it's safe. When a variable is declared as class global, any thread can modify its value. But in case of a local variable (a variable declared inside a function), that variable is not reachable from other threads, so safe to use.

Comment: @DivyaGupta, Farid is correct, it is null safe. See [Null Safety - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't adding local variables beat the purpose of DataBinding? I'm more confused.

Comment: @mfulton26, i know that it's and old post but i will be glad to understand what happens when *add* function get a *return* as an argument. I have never seen a think like this before

Comment: @Eitanos30, here `return` is used as an expression which means `add` never gets called if `left` is `null`; execution flow returns from whatever functions contains this statement.

Comment: @Eitanos30 It does drive people crazy but it's, actually, great, if not warned by IDE you could've simply overlooked it.

Answer (score 71):

**1)** Also you can use `lateinit` If you are **sure** you will do your initialization later on `onCreate()` or elsewhere.

Use this

```
lateinit var left: Node
```

Instead of this

```
var left: Node? = null
```

**2)** And there is other way that use `!!` end of variable when you use it like this

```
queue.add(left!!) // add !!
```

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: @c-an it make your variable initialize as null but expect sure to initialize later in code.

Comment: Then, isn't it the same? @Radesh

Comment: @c-an same with what?

Comment: `lateinit var left: Node` and `var left: Node? = null`

Comment: i answered above question that is 
Smart cast to 'Node' is impossible, because 'left' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

this code prevent that error by specify variable kind. so compiler no need for smart cast

Comment: Although the answer could be helpful to some, don't forget that you're prohibiting the value of the variable to be `null` when you declare it as `lateinit var left: Node`

Answer (score 33):

There is a fourth option in addition to the ones in mfulton26's answer.

By using the `?.` operator it is possible to call methods as well as fields without dealing with `let` or using local variables.

Some code for context:

```
var factory: ServerSocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
socket = factory.createServerSocket(port)
socket.close()//smartcast impossible
socket?.close()//Smartcast possible. And works when called
```

It works with methods, fields and all the other things I tried to get it to work.

So in order to solve the issue, instead of having to use manual casts or using local variables, you can use `?.` to call the methods.

For reference, this was tested in Kotlin `1.1.4-3`, but also tested in `1.1.51` and `1.1.60`. There's no guarantee it works on other versions, it could be a new feature.

Using the `?.` operator can't be used in your case since it's a passed variable that's the problem. The Elvis operator can be used as an alternative, and it's probably the one that requires the least amount of code. Instead of using `continue` though, `return` could also be used.

Using manual casting could also be an option, but this isn't null safe:

```
queue.add(left as Node);
```

Meaning if left **has changed** on a different thread, the program will crash.

Comment: As far as I understand, the '?.' operator is checking if the variable on its left side is null.. In the example above it would be 'queue'. The error 'smart cast impossible' is referring to the parameter "left" being passed into the method "add"... I still get the error if I use this approach

Comment: Right, the error is on `left` and not `queue`. Need to check this, will edit the answer in a minute

Answer (score 7):

The practical reason why this doesn't work is not related to threads. The point is that `node.left` is effectively translated into `node.getLeft()`.

This property getter might be defined as:

```
val left get() = if (Math.random() < 0.5) null else leftPtr
```

Therefore two calls might not return the same result.

Comment: This answer is only applicable to properties defined in other classes. For `val`s defined in the same class as the current function, the compiler checks if it has a custom getter or not and it can smart cast if it doesn’t. For `var`s, even if there is no custom getter, it cannot smart cast and the practical reason really is that another thread could have changed it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Or would it be wiser for both of us to just refer to the language specification, which defines the properties where smart casts are applicable? I guess the correct section is [14.3.1 Smart cast sink stability](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#smart-cast-sink-stability).

Answer (score 7):

Change `var left: Node? = null` to `lateinit var left: Node`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Your most elegant solution must be:

```
var left: Node? = null

fun show() {
    left?.also {
        queue.add( it )
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to define a new and unnecessary local variable, and you don't have any new assertions or casts (which are not DRY). Other scope functions could also work so choose your favourite.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var left: Node? = null

fun show() {
     val left = left
     if (left != null) {
         queue.add(left) // safe cast succeeds
     }
}
```

Which seems to be the first option provided by the accepted answer, but that's what you're looking for.

Comment: This is shadowing of "left" variable?

Comment: Which is totally ok. See https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/fdp2zq/is_name_shadowing_not_recommended/fjj2c7k/

Answer (score 1):

For future viewers, especially Kotlin newcomers with js/ts background

Since this is the most popular question about `Smart cast to 'Type' is impossible` problems, I would like to elaborate on what did brought me here.
My case was to simply transform nullable `var` instance into the another class instance but I was getting errors like this one:
`Smart cast to 'TestClass' is impossible, because 'testObject' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time`

```kotlin
data class TestClass(
  val x: String,
  val y: String
)

data class FooClass(
  val x: String,
  val y: String
)

var testObject: Testclass? = Testclass("x", "y")

val transformed = testObject?.let { FooClass(x = testObject.x, y = testObject.y) }
```

and I didn't really understand what was wrong, since I've used safe call operator and everything was looking fine!

But then I realized, Kotlin in comparison to JS is multi-threaded, so in theory a mutable variable could be changed, and then I realized my mistake - I used `testObject` variable directly instead of using `it`

```kotlin
val transformed = testObject?.let { FooClass(x = testObject.x, y = testObject.y) }
```

so the correct solution is

```kotlin
val transformed = testObject?.let { FooClass(x = it.x, y = it.y) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the not-null assertion operator...

```
queue.add(left!!)
```

Comment: Dangerous. For the same reason the auto-casting doesn't work.

Comment: It may cause app crash if left is null.

Comment: How can it be null? Code in question checks it: "if (left != null)". If the value could change to null it could change to another value, too. The app would crash but the results of the method could be unexpected.

Comment: Literally, the error given by Kotlin (in the title of the question) tells you that it could have changed. Either you are smarter than the compiler (rarely the case) or this is possible when there are multiple threads running (which always is the case in Android, you at least have a UI thread + several worker threads).

Answer (score 0):

For there to be a Smart Cast of the properties, **the data type of the property must be the class that contains the method** or behavior that you want to access and NOT that the property is of the type of the super class.

---

### e.g on Android

Be:

```
class MyVM : ViewModel() {
    fun onClick() {}
}
```

Solution:

```
From: private lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
To: private lateinit var viewModel: MyVM
```

Usage:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyVM::class.java]
viewModel.onClick {}
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

How I would write it:

```
var left: Node? = null

fun show() {
     val left = left ?: return
     queue.add(left) // no error because we return if it is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform as below :-

```
var left: Node? = null
```

> Use a null safe call

```
left?.let { node -> queue.add(node) } // The most preferred one
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:
**private lateinit var varName: String**

Comment: I encountered the same error while accessing a variable in a viewModel