# Nullable var and smart cast

Tags: kotlin, null, kotlin-null-safety

Consider the following block of Kotlin.

```kotlin
var nullableInt: Int? = null

if (nullableInt != null) {
    val checkedInt: Int = nullableInt
    print("not-null-branch")
} else {
    print("null-branch")
}
```

Android Studio tells me that the smart cast from `Int?` to `Int` is not possible, since `nullableInt` is mutable. I understand that this may be a problem in multithreaded code.

One way to handle the problem is to make an explicit cast with  `val checkedInt: Int = nullableInt!!`, but if I would use the coded in a multithread environment that is not advisable.

---

#### Close duplicates

There are a couple of very close questions on SO regarding this topic. However, I don't find a satistafctory answer in any of the ones I've found:

[In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values, referencing or converting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o) discusses why the problem arises, but provides no suggestion on how to handle it

[Kotlin avoid smart cast for null check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380288/kotlin-avoid-smart-cast-for-null-check) has a if-not-null branch that returns a non-null value, so the `?.let{} :? {}` construct works there. Since my not-null-branch returns null, both branches would run.

[Kotlin "Smart cast is impossible, because the property could have been changed by this time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701042/kotlin-smart-cast-is-impossible-because-the-property-could-have-been-changed-b) concerns only with a not-null-branch and no null-branch, so the `?.let{}` construct seems correct. In that thread, they provide the suggestion about taking a local copy before the `if` statement, which could be doable in my case too. It is unfortunately not very elegant, and I hope there is some other alternative.

---

Is there any way to handle this null-conditional branching in a null safe manner without taking a copy?

I understand that the answer potentially could be "it depends". If that is the case, please say so and elaborate on why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use `.let` instead of `?.let`

Because the `.let`  extension function is defined for all types, including nullable ones, you can actually call it without the safe-call `?.` operator. When you do that, the lambda will always be called, even for `null` values. The parameter inside the `let` block will be nullable if the receiver is nullable.

However, the lambda parameter ***is* eligible for smart casting**, because it isn't mutable.

Here's the difference:

```kotlin
x.let { it -> /* This always runs. 'it' can be null if 'x' is null */ }
x?.let { it -> /* This only runs if 'x' is not null. 'it' is never null. */ }
```

Applying that to your example, you could write this:

```kotlin
var nullableInt: Int? = null

nullableInt.let {
    if (it != null) {
         doSomethingWith(it)
    } else {
         doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can’t start-cast a property because another thread could be modifying it. There is no logical way around that. The language already provides an unsafe way to do it with the `!!` that you already mentioned.

Making a local copy of the reference (either manually or by using a scope function like `with` or `let`) is trivial so it’s not something you need to worry about.

My personal opinion is that a local variable is the cleanest, most readable way to do it. You avoid the nesting of blocks you’d have with scope functions.

```
val myVar = myProp
if (myVar != null) {

} else {

}
```

I think the cleanest way with scope functions is to use `with`. It reads better than `let` when you’re handling both branches.

```
with(myProp) {
    if (this != null) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

For a concise way to handle both branches, the following works. I consider `also` to be a little more robust than `let` for this situation, because you can’t accidentally run both branches by returning a null from the first lambda. But the readability suffers from going this concise.

```
myProp?.also {
    // not null it
} ?: run {
    // null
}
```