# smart cast impossible because instance is mutable property

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a singleton in Kotlin and am running into problems because I get a `smart cast to PresenterManager is impossible because instance is mutable property that could have been changed at this time`.

This seems like a pretty standard way to make a singleton. Why won't it let me and how can I fix it?

```
PresenterManager {
    //some code
    ....

    companion object {
        private val PRESENTER_ID = "presenter_id"
        private var instance: PresenterManager? = null

        fun getManager(): PresenterManager {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = PresenterManager(10, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kotlin already has Singleton implementation. Look at doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart cast to 'Type' is impossible, because 'variable' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595529/smart-cast-to-type-is-impossible-because-variable-is-a-mutable-property-tha)

Answer (score 2):

> This seems like a pretty standard way to make a singleton.

I do recommend you to read a bit more about Kotlin.

```
object PresenterManager {
    init {
       // init code
    }

    fun whatever() {}
}
```

What I wrote above is a Singleton in Kotlin. Now, to explain the message you are getting:

> smart cast to PresenterManager is impossible because instance is mutable property that could have been changed at this time

`instance` is nullable (`private var instance: PresenterManager? = null`), and the `getManager` function expects a non-null return type, so one of the many ways of solving this is by either make `getManager` return a nullable type (`fun getManager(): PresenterManager?`) or make use of the `!!` operator on your return type.

The main point is that you really don't need of that `instance` variable at all if you use an `object` instead of a `class` to declare your singleton.

Comment: Or `instance` could be made non-null and [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties)

Comment: It can also be lazy-instantiated using `by lazy { PresenterManager() }`. My point answering this question isn't about the options available for making `instance` non-null but to rather explain there's no need for it in first place and explain the reason behind the lint error :)