# Smart cast is impossible, because ... is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: multithreading, casting, kotlin

I am trying to get a class, which combines list, set and map in `Kotlin`. I wished to write `isScalar` function, which should return `true` if object contains only one element and wrote

```
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.Reference2ReferenceOpenHashMap
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.ReferenceArrayList
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.ReferenceOpenHashSet

class Args {

    var list : ReferenceArrayList<M>? = null

    var set : ReferenceOpenHashSet<M>? = null

    var map : Reference2ReferenceOpenHashMap<M, M>? = null

    fun isEmpty() : Boolean {
        return list === null && set === null && map === null
    }

    fun isScalar() : Boolean {
        if(list !== null && list.size == 1) {
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately it gave me error in comparison

```
list !== null && list.size == 1
```

saying

```
Smart cast to 'ReferenceArrayList<M>' is impossible, because 'list' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time
```

As far as I understood, this is related with multithreaded assumption. In Java I would make function `synchronized` if would expect multithreding. Also, I would be able to disregard this at all, if I am not writing thread-safe.

How should I write in Kotlin?

I saw this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596284/258483 but it expects MT, which I don't want to. How to avoid smart casting if it can't do it?

**UPDATE**

The question is how to do this in the same "procedural" form. How not to use smart casting?

**UPDATE 2**

Summarizing, as far as I understood, it is not possible/reasonable to explicitly compare variable with `null` in Kotlin at all. Because once you compare it, next time yous hould compare it with `null` again implicitly with such operations like `.?` and you can't avoid this.

Comment: The solution you saw doesn't "expect MT", it explains why Kotlin's static analysis works as it does. `How to avoid smart casting if it can't do it?`---by not requesting it. Your `list.size == 1` requests a smart cast which Kotlin refuses.

Comment: Making a method `synchronized` wouldn't be nearly enough to make it impossible to update an instance variable from another thread. In fact, there is nothing you can do to stop it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik so how not to request smart casting?

Comment: You need help with the syntax? `list!!.size` will avoid a smart cast. So will `list?.size`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik incredible, I am very confused

Comment: It's hard to find where exactly you need help. Your `list` is a nullable type, you can't just dereference it.

Comment: I already ensured it is not `null`, then I can dereference it.

Comment: You can't ensure an instance variable is not `null`. The next time you load it, it may have become `null`. There is nothing you can do to make that _theoretically impossible_.

Comment: What's the difference with other values? Suppose I checked variable is equal to `2`. Next line I also can't be sure it is still `2` because somebody could change it. Hence, no programming is possible at all!

Comment: All you have to do is load an instance variable into a local variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take advantage of the fact that `null` cannot equal `1` (or anything else, really), you can make this check very concise:

```
fun isScalar() : Boolean =
    list?.size == 1
```

When a null-safe call to `list.size` returns null, we get `false` because `1 != null`. Otherwise, a comparison of whatever value `size` returns is made, and that works as you would expect.

By using the null safe operator (`?.`) you are avoiding a smart cast entirely. Kotlin gives us smart casts to make code cleaner, and this is one of the ways it protects us from misuses *of that feature*. Kotlin isn't going to protect us from everything (division by zero, the example you use in comments, for example). Your code is getting caught up in a legitimate case of where smart casting can go wrong, so Kotlin jumps in to help.

However, if you are absolutely sure there are no other threads working, then yes, this check is "wrong". You wouldn't need the warning in that case. Judging by [this thread on kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/smart-casts-and-nullability-in-single-threaded-contexts/4562/9), you aren't the only one!

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is `.?` operator, but I want to understand, how to decompose

Comment: What do you mean by "how to decompose"? I'm not following you. There's no way to turn off the check that another thread could come in and change the meaning of `list`, so you have to work around it by not requesting a safe cast.

Comment: No. There is no way to turn that off. However the code from both answers (me and @zsmb13) are both idomatic Kotlin.

Comment: What is the purpose of message saying "smart cast is impossible" with simulatneously having smart cast is unavoidable?

Comment: suppose another code `if( a != 0 ) { b = c / a }` and a compiler which swears that it may cause division by zero because some thread can change `a` to zero between check and execution! this destroys all programming logic at all!

Comment: Because you aren't smartcasting by using `?.let` or `?.size`, you are doing nullsafe traversals. No smart cast happens there.

Comment: `a` isn't being cast in that case, it's always (presumably) an `Int`. So the compiler isn't looking to protect you from a common source of errors in that case. It is trying to protect you when you smart cast (which again, this isn't).

Comment: Division by zero is relatively common source of errors. Why not compiler protects me from it with special version of division? Why if protects me from `null` even against my will?

Comment: You should address these questions at the Kotlin creators. They made certain design choices that they saw as useful. For me, null-safety is great. For you, it isn't. This is no place for either arguing over it or asking Kotlin users to answer in the name of its creators.

Comment: I need explanation. Null safety may be good, but neither service is good, if it is a must. Anyway, your answer looks best for me, because you used implicit checking for `null` inside `.?` only.

Comment: Null safety is no different from any other static analysis you care to name. They all follow strict formal rules and can never be _complete_, i.e., have no false positives and no false negatives. That is a _theoretical impossibility_. Furthermore, there is no statically typed language out there that allows you to disable any formal rule at any time There are always some rules that are "a must" and the designers have a very hard time finding the right balance between safe strictness and dangerous laxness.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform the null check, and if it succeeds, access a read-only copy of your variable with [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html):

```
fun isScalar() : Boolean {
    return list?.let { it.size == 1 } ?: false
}
```

- If `list` is null, the entire `let` expression will evaluate to `null`, and the right side of the Elvis operator (`false`) will be returned.
- If `list` is not null, then the `let` function is called, and result of the `it.size == 1` expression is returned - `it` refers to the object that `let` was called on (`list` in this case). Since it's used with a [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls), this `it` will have a non-nullable type and `size` can be called on it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in the given lines

```
 sliderView.setSliderAdapter(adapter!!)
 sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM)
```

Finally, error resolved by adding !!

```
 sliderView!!.setSliderAdapter(adapter!!)
 sliderView!!.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM)
```

Comment: You should always try to avoid (!! not-null assertions) as it can lead to app crashes and weird behavior. Only use it when you are sure that the given value will never be null otherwise it will throw a NPE