# Smart cast to 'ArrayList<Object>' is impossible in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some classes and I have converted them from *Java* to *Kotlin*.

This is the *Kotlin* method:

```
private var allCountriesList: List<Country>? = null

        val allCountries: List<Country>
            get() {

                val locales = Locale.getISOCountries()
                val countries = ArrayList<Country>()

                for (countryCode in locales) {

                    val obj = Locale("", countryCode)
                    Log.i("AMIRA2020", obj.country + " / " + obj.displayName)
                    if (obj.country == "SP" == false && obj.country == "ZG" == false)
                        countries.add(Country(obj.country, obj.displayName, -1))
                }

                Collections.sort(countries) { o1, o2 -> o1.name!!.compareTo(o2.name!!) }

                allCountriesList = countries

                return allCountriesList
            }
```

I am getting an error in the `return` statement that the smart case is impossible.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart cast to 'Type' is impossible, because 'variable' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595529/smart-cast-to-type-is-impossible-because-variable-is-a-mutable-property-tha)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `allCountriesList` is a nullable property, and `allCountries` has to return a non-null value. You might expect that setting `allCountriesList` to a non-null List before returning it makes this safe, but it doesn't.

For example, between these two lines, another thread could get CPU time, and set `allCountriesList` back to `null`, which you can't return from the getter of `allCountries`.

```
allCountriesList = countries
return allCountriesList
```

So the solution is to return the list you know to be non-null within this scope (and not accessible from other threads), `countries`:

```
val allCountries: List<Country>
    get() {

        ...
        val countries = ArrayList<Country>()
        ...

        allCountriesList = countries

        return countries
    }
```

Comment: it does not work when I remove the null initialization, it works when I use this var allCountriesList: List<Country> = emptyList()