# Smart cast to "GridLayoutManager" is impossible, because 'ViewManager' is a mutable property that could have changed by this time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

"Smart cast to "GridLayoutManager" is impossible, because 'ViewManager' is a mutable property that could have changed by this time"

is the Error that AndroidStudio shows when trying to add a Divider to my RecyclerView.

*PixelsFragment.kt*

```
class PixelsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null
    private lateinit var pixels: List<Pixel>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var numberOfColumns = 1

        viewManager = GridLayoutManager(this.context, numberOfColumns)
        viewAdapter = MyRecyclerViewAdapter(pixels)


        recyclerView = view!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.RVJanuary).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
            addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.context, viewManager.getOrientation())) //Error on this line, underlining viewManager
        }


    }
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596284/6818446) which says that such a problem can be caused because the variable could happen to be `null` by the time that the line is executed, and then they provide 3 solutions. However, to my understanding, `viewManager` can by no means be `null` since I declared it as non-nullable variable. Therefore, I am looking for a different explanation and solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declare `viewManager` as a `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`. The generic `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` does not have a `getOrientation()` method - [that method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager#getorientation) only exists on [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager) and its subclasses, such as the [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager) that you are using.

What the error message is telling you is that it cannot assume that the `viewManager` of type `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` is a `GridLayoutManager` since it is a mutable property - you could have set it to some other `LayoutManager` that does not have a `getOrientation()` method.

The easiest way to solve this is to change the type of your `viewManager` to `GridLayoutManager`. That way, only a `GridLayoutManager` would be available and `getOrientation()` is guaranteed to be available.