# Why does the system display 'Smart cast to 'File' is impossible' in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Code A1 I have used the `let` statement, so I think it will not be null with `filenameofVideo.path`

But I get the following error, why?

*Smart cast to 'File' is impossible, because 'filenameofVideo' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time*

At this moment, I have to use Code A2.

**Code A1**

```
private var filenameofVideo :File?=null

filenameofVideo?.let {
          Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container)
               .navigate(UIFragmentCameraDirections.actionCameraToVideo(filenameofVideo.path))
}
```

**Code A2**

```
private var filenameofVideo :File?=null

filenameofVideo?.let {filenameofVideo ->
        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container)
            .navigate(UIFragmentCameraDirections.actionCameraToVideo(filenameofVideo.path))
}
```

And more, I find both Code B1 and Code B2 are correct. Why is Code B1 correct and Code A1 wrong?

**Code B1**

```
   private val aa:String?=null
   aa?.let {
            print(aa)
        }
```

**Code B2**

```
private val aa:String?=null    
   aa?.let{aa->
           print(aa)
      }
```

**Added Content:**

1:  In Code C, the var aa  might have been changed (perhaps by another thread) between the moment it is accessed in the ?.let call and the moment it is accessed within the let block.

Code C will be launched when aa is not null, and Code C will not launched when aa is null, right?

2:  In Code D (I assume the compiler accept it ), the function always be launched no matter aa is null or not, it can not be accepted, so the system will interrupt, right?

**Code C**

```
private var aa: String? = null    
aa?.let { kk ->
    print(kk.length)
}
```

**Code D**

```
private var aa: String? = null    
aa?.let {
    print(aa.length)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart cast to 'Type' is impossible, because 'variable' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595529/smart-cast-to-type-is-impossible-because-variable-is-a-mutable-property-tha)

Comment: Thanks！but Code A has used  safe call `let`

Comment: But you are using the property again instead of “it”.

Comment: Thanks! But you can't use `it` because it's nest lamabad expression

Comment: Simply name the parameter instead of using `it` then.

Comment: Use `filenameofVideo?.let {filenameofVideo -> //...` and it will shadow its own property so you can use `filenameofVideo` within the `let` block after all.

Comment: Thanks! your code `filenameofVideo?.let {filenameofVideo -> //... ` works well, but why doesn't the Code A work?

Comment: I think `filenameofVideo?.let {filenameofVideo -> //... ` is the same as Code A.

Answer (score 2):

Let's trim your code down a bit so that it's a little easier to discuss:

> ```
> private var filename :File?=null
>
> filename?.let {
>     action(filename.path)
> }
> ```

The problem here is that, even though you've called `?.let`, the compiler cannot guarantee that `filename` is not null inside the `let` block. This is because `filename` is a `var`, and the value of the `var` might have been changed (perhaps by another thread) between the moment it is accessed in the `?.let` call and the moment it is accessed within the `let` block.

Therefore, you must handle the possibility of null yourself. The easiest way to do this will be to use the `it` value inside the `let` block, or to name that value yourself:

```
filename?.let { safe ->
    action(safe.path)
}
```

The reason that this code **does** work:

> ```
> private val aa:String?=null
> aa?.let {
>     print(aa)
> }
> ```

is that here the variable is a `val`. This means that it will either be `null` or non-null, but either way *it can't change*. So you and I can read the code and see that the `.let` block will never be executed... but if somehow it *were*, that would mean that `aa` is guaranteed to not be null, and so the compiler can smart-cast it to a non-nullable type.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Answer (score 1):

The code like

```
private var aa: String? = null
aa?.let {
    print(aa.length)
}
```

does not compile because, while the safe call `?.let { }` block is executed only if `aa`  property is not null, by the time the execution reaches `aa.length`, the value of `aa` property might have been already changed to null in another thread.

On the other hand, in this example

```
private var aa: String? = null    
aa?.let { aa ->
    print(aa.length)
}
```

the non-null value of `aa` property is captured after the safe call in the read-only `aa` parameter of the lambda passed to `let`.

Note that making `aa` property `val` instead of `var` as in your example B1 also helps to eliminate the error, but that causes the `let` block be never executed since a private val initialized to null can never become non-null.

As for the additional question about what is a difference between the examples C and D:

- there's no difference in how the `let { }` function is executed. In both cases the lambda function is launched only when the receiver expression `aa` is not null, because you use `?.` safe call operator.
- the example D isn't accepted by the compiler because it can't ensure the value of `aa` property referenced inside lambda hasn't been changed by the time execution reaches that line.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: I've edited the answer to address this additional question.