# Does setting a var class member a new value can change is type?

Tags: kotlin, casting, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

I pretty sure that the answer to the question in title is No.
But i wrote a simple code and get a weird error when trying to compile.
code:

```
open class Animal (val stttt:String, val str:String = "hjm") {
    open var fff: String = ""
    open var image = ""
    open val food = ""
    open val habitat = ""
    var hunger: Int? = 10
}

 class Hippo ( var strrr:Int = 7) : Animal("just") {
     override var image = "hippo.jpg"
     override var food = "grass"
     override val habitat = "water"
 }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val hippo: Hippo? = Hippo()
    hippo?.hunger = 5
    println(hippo?.hunger)  // println(hippo?.hunger as Int?) works!!
}
```

the last line in code:

> println(hippo?.hunger)  // println(hippo?.hunger as Int?) works!!

makes the compiler display the following error:

> smart cast to Int is impossible, because hippo?.hunger is a mutable property that could have been changed  by this time

**But**, if i remove the following line the code is compiled:

> hippo?.hunger = 5

Can someone explain me, what is wrong with this line of code that prevents the code from being compiled successfully?

[image]

Comment: Both lines work for me, your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Nicolas, i have added a screen shot that shows that there is an error. Please help me to clarify the unclear things

Comment: @Alex.T, no it isn't. You can see that i'm using to safe call. The issue related to the line hippo?.hunger = 5 which for some reason (this is really the question) makes to an  error in println call

Comment: @Alex.T, hi mate. After i have explain you with it isn't the same question. Can you close the duplicate request you have opened?

Comment: sure thing, just did

Comment: @Alex.T can you please add the link you wrote before? i want to learn something from there :) .. I will delete the comment after i will get an answer from you

Comment: this was the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595529/smart-cast-to-type-is-impossible-because-variable-is-a-mutable-property-tha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs just fine as posted: [Kotlin Playground example](https://pl.kotl.in/_DL8TqiKQ)

That error usually comes up where you've checked something isn't null, so you can treat it as a non-null type (`Int` in this case), but that doesn't work for `var`s because they can change, and could be null again - so you need to use something like `hippo?.hunger?.let { bla bla }` where the value gets assigned to a temporary `val` (`it` by default) which can't be changed.

I'm not sure why you're getting the error there, maybe it's trying to use the `println(message: Int)` call instead of the `println(message: Any?)` call for some reason? You can put the cursor on `println` and do `ctrl+Q` (or your equivalent) to find out which function it thinks it's calling.

But yeah, if the smart casting is messing you around, it's probably a bug. Casting to `Int?` like you're doing is one way of doing it, or doing the `let/run` thing might work too (`hippo?.hunger.run(::println)`).

Is your main block closed by the way? The curly brace is missing

Comment: 1. as you thought it's trying to use the **println(message: Int)**. I can't understand why :(   2.When you say *But yeah, if the smart casting is messing you around, it's probably a bug* do you mean a bug in compiler or bug the way my head is thinking? :)   3. it works with *let*. since i don't know what is run and double :: i didn't try it  4. yes, my main block is closed

Comment: it is interesting how the line hippo?.hunger = 5 makes this problem. Didn't it reproduceable in your station?

Comment: The link I posted is from the Kotlin site where you can run some code, I pasted yours in and it didn't complain - it looks like it's an issue with the Kotlin plugin your IDE is using. For what it's worth, I pasted it into Android Studio (you're using IntelliJ, right? It's based on that) and it didn't complain, no error messages and it's using the ``Any?`` version. Try seeing if there are any updates to your plugins, maybe it's an issue that got fixed?

Comment: ``run`` is the same as ``let``, except with ``let`` you're passing in a parameter (called ``it`` by default) and ``run`` uses it as a receiver (the variable becomes ``this`` in the function, basically). ``thing.run(::println)`` is just shorthand for ``thing.run { println(this) }``, sorry! I just like it because it's neat, you can do it with ``thing.let(::println)`` too (same as ``thing.let { println(it) }``. I'd use ``let`` if you're writing the lambda out and passing the parameter in, just looks better than passing in ``this``. Nothing to do with the question but sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @ cactustictacs, updating plugin really solved the issue. I will approve your answer. You helped  me a lot. Plugin :( ...  Can you please explain what do you mean when saying: *writing the lambda out and passing the parameter in*, i will be more than happy to understand :)

Comment: Oh it's this stuff: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type , or this might be a good explanation: https://proandroiddev.com/the-difference-between-kotlins-functions-let-apply-with-run-and-else-ca51a4c696b8 - don't worry about it, ``let`` and ``run`` are the same thing, you just use the value in different ways and I just prefer ``thing.let { doSomething(it) }`` over ``thing.run { doSomething(this) }``, and I prefer ``thing.run { this.whatever() }`` (without the ``this``) over ``thing.let { it.whatever() }``. It doesn't really matter!

Comment: @ cactustictacs thanks You!! When saying *thing.run { this.whatever() } (without the this)*, do you mean that this is redundant?

Comment: When you call a function on ``this``, like ``this.doThing()``, you don't need to explicitly include ``this`` - I just included it to show that when you use ``run`` the lambda acts on the object itself, if you use ``let`` the object is passed in as a parameter (called ``it``) instead. You can use whichever you like. You should read those links though, I can't really explain it in comments!