# Smart cast to 'Type!' is impossible, because 'variable' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, kotlin-android

I would really appreciate if someone will help me.

I'm trying to make an app using kotlin for android  and am running into problems because I get errors like "**Smart cast to 'Button!' is impossible, because 'activityButton1' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time**"
I would really appreciate if someone will help me to fix this problem. Here is my code-

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var activityButton1: Button? = null
    private var spinnerList: Spinner? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        activityButton1 = findViewById(R.id.clickMe)
        spinnerList = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        val intentTo3 = Intent(this@MainActivity, ThirdActivity::class.java)
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
        activityButton1.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val optionSelected = spinnerList.getSelectedItem().toString()
            if (optionSelected.equals("Custom BroadCast Receiver", ignoreCase = true)) {
                intent.putExtra("name", "custom")
                startActivity(intent)
            } else if (optionSelected.equals(
                    "System Battery notification receiver",
                    ignoreCase = true
                )
            ) {
                intent.putExtra("name", "battery")
                startActivity(intent)
            } else if (optionSelected.equals("Wifi RTT state change receiver", ignoreCase = true)) {
                intentTo3.putExtra("name", "rtt")
                startActivity(intentTo3)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two mutable properties :

```
private var activityButton1: Button? = null
```

and

```
private var spinnerList: Spinner? = null
```

If you want to use those values freely you have two solutions :

#### Using another val to store value

When you want to use a mutable property at some point of your code, you can simply create an immutable variable (val) that will old the value of your mutable property.

#### Using lateint

The best way is to use a [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) property.

```
 private lateinit var activityButton1: Button
 private lateinit var spinnerList: Spinner
```

with lateinit property you ensure that at one point you will give a value to the properties. If you are trying to access the value before initializing, it will throw an error,

Answer (score 0):

Change your views like this:

```
private lateinit var activityButton1: Button
private lateinit var spinnerList: Spinner
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595529/smart-cast-to-type-is-impossible-because-variable-is-a-mutable-property-tha) may help you for further information

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way you can achive your goal by initializing your var as lateinit.

private lateinit var activityButton1: Button ? = null

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin can access view element without having findViewById() method.

You can read in develop: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding