# Can I smartCast within the when statement?

Tags: kotlin

I have the code below

```
class Sample {

   var variable1: SomeClass? = null
   var variable2: SomeClass? = null
   var variable3: SomeClass? = null


   fun checkVariable() {
      when {
         variable1 != null -> variable1!!.doSomething()
         variable2 != null -> variable2!!.doSomething()
         variable3 != null -> variable3!!.doSomething()
      }
   }

}
```

I'm hoping I can make `variableX` after the `->` non-nullable, so I don't need to `!!`.
I can avoid `!!` with

```
variable1 !== null -> variable1?.doSomething()
```

But is there away to do this more elegantly that I can have a non-nullable variable to access the `doSomething()`?

Comment: Smartcast is impossible with `var`. Use `val` and it works as you intended.

Comment: Assume I need a `var` instead of `val`

Comment: If the methods return **non-nullable** then `fun getStrLength() = variable1?.getEenie() ?: variable2?.getMeenie() ?: variable3?.getMiny()`

Answer (score 3):

The error is not because of the `when`. [You just cannot smart cast class-level `var`s.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44595529/5133585)

In this case, since all your variables are of the same type and you are doing the same thing on all of them, your code can be simplified to:

```
(variable1 ?: variable2 ?: variable3)?.doSomething()
```

In other words, you are finding the first non-null out of the three variables, and calling `doSomething` on it.

If your variables are not of the same type, and you are doing different things to each of them, you can do:

```
variable1?.also {
    it.doSomething()
} ?: variable2?.also {
    it.doSomethingElse()
} ?: variable3?.also {
    it.doAnotherThing()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's more elegant but you could maybe write this instead:

```
fun getStrLength() = (variable1 ?: variable2 ?: variable3)?.doSomething()
```

Another way to remove the `!!` is to first store them in local variables like

```
fun getStrLengths() { 
    val variable1 = variable1
    val variable2 = variable2 
    val variable3 = variable3  
    when { 
        variable1 != null -> variable1.doSomething() 
        variable2 != null -> variable2.doSomething() 
        variable3 != null -> variable3.doSomething() 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Lazy initialisation

You could make the properties non-nullable with [`lateinit var`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables).

This would prevent the need for any null checks.

You can check to see if the properties are present with [`isInitialized`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized) instead of a non-null check.

```kotlin
class Sample {
  lateinit var variable1: SomeClass
  lateinit var variable2: SomeClass
  lateinit var variable3: SomeClass

  fun checkVariable() {
    when {
      // so long as a value is initialised, there is no need for null checks
      ::variable1.isInitialized -> variable1.printName()
      ::variable2.isInitialized -> variable2.printName()
      ::variable3.isInitialized -> variable3.printName()
    }
  }
}

class SomeClass(val name: String) {
  fun printName() {
    println(name)
  }
}
```

##### Unsetting values

This can be useful to avoid null checks, but it would prevent 'unsetting' previously set variables with `null`.

```
val sample = Sample()

sample.variable1 = SomeClass("foo")

sample.variable1 = null // ERROR: Null can not be a value of a non-null type SomeClass
```

Whether unsetting values is required or not depends on your use-case.

##### Example

```kotlin
fun main() {

  val sample = Sample()

  println("first check:")
  sample.checkVariable()
  println("---")

  sample.variable3 = SomeClass("Jamie")

  println("second check:")
  sample.checkVariable()
  println("---")

  sample.variable2 = SomeClass("Maddie")

  println("third check:")
  sample.checkVariable()
  println("---")

  sample.variable1 = SomeClass("Lisa")

  println("fourth check:")
  sample.checkVariable()
  println("---")
}
```

We can see that as each variable is set, other variables are not called, as they are listed lower in the `when` statement.

```kotlin
first check:
---
second check:
Jamie
---
third check:
Maddie
---
fourth check:
Lisa
---
```

Comment: IMO, replacing null-checks with `isInitialized` checks is a poor solution because it erases null-safety. At least a nullable forces you to consider whether it is safe to use and acknowledge that you checked the behavior by marking it with `!!`. If you aren’t initializing a `lateinit` property at the class entry-point, I don’t think it should be used at all, because you are pushing your error checking to runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It completely depends on the situation. Given the limited context that OP provided, it's impossible to say what is a poor solution or not. There are good reasons why `lateinit var` is a language feature.

Comment: I think the good reason to use it is when your class entry point is not the constructor because your class is a subclass of something that does initialization of subclasses somewhere besides the constructor. If you are having to check `isInitialized` in random places outside the class entry point, I believe it is a misuse of `lateinit`. Just an opinion--everyone is free to ignore the null-safety features of Kotlin if they want to.