# Cant fix this error: "Smart cast to 'Node' is impossible, because 'node.left' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time"

Tags: kotlin

I keep getting this issue when using android studio (kotlin) and trying to design a decision app for android:

Smart cast to 'Node' is impossible, because 'node.left' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time:104

Smart cast to 'Node' is impossible, because 'node.right' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time:110

The code im trying to build is to make a small decision tree that i will expand on later.
I am only trying to get the code to work and emulate it, i will design and such later.

This is my code:

```
package com.example.myapplication6

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.example.myapplication6.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()


        // A class to represent a node in the decision tree
        class Node {
            val data: String
            var left: Node?
            var right: Node?

            constructor(data: String, left: Node?, right: Node?) {
                this.data = data
                this.left = left
                this.right = right

        fun main() {
            // Create the root node of the decision tree with the question "Do you want to go to the social gathering?"
            val root = Node("Do you want to go to the social gathering?", null, null)

            // Create the left and right child nodes of the root node with the answers "Yes" and "No" respectively
            val yesNode = Node("Yes", null, null)
            val noNode = Node("No", null, null)

            // Set the left and right child nodes of the root node to the "Yes" and "No" nodes respectively
            root.left = yesNode
            root.right = noNode

            // Create the final level of nodes with the answers "Yes" and "No"
            val yesLeaf = Node("Yes", null, null)
            val noLeaf = Node("No", null, null)

            // Set the left and right child nodes of the "Yes" and "No" nodes from the previous level
            yesNode.left = yesLeaf
            yesNode.right = noLeaf
            noNode.left = noLeaf
            noNode.right = noLeaf

            // Create a list to store the decision tree nodes
            val nodes = mutableListOf(root)

            // Traverse the decision tree and print the question at each node
            while (nodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                val node = nodes.removeAt(0)
                println(node.data)



                // If the node has a left child, add it to the list of nodes
                if (node.left != null) {
                    nodes.add(node.left)
                }


                // If the node has a right child, add it to the list of nodes
                if (node.right != null) {
                    nodes.add(node.right)
                }
            }
        }


            }
        }


    }
}
```

I tried changing the node and defining it differntly but it didnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smart cast to 'Type' is impossible, because 'variable' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595529/smart-cast-to-type-is-impossible-because-variable-is-a-mutable-property-tha)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has null-safety built into the compiler. This means it'll prevent you from trying to add nullable things (like `node.left`) to things that can't contain them (such as your `MutableList<Node>`).

"But I've done a null check just the line before!"

Yes, and usually that would be sufficient. But Kotlin knows that the `left` property of `node` is mutable, and so it could technically have been changed (from not `null` to `null` in between the null check and the add statement. That's what's generating the error.

You have two options here:

If you are very sure that there are no other threads changing nodes, you can tell the compiler "don't worry about it, I know this thing won't be null": `nodes.add(node.left!!)`. However, this will cause a `NullPointerException` at runtime if you are wrong.

If you're not sure, you can simply only add the node if it's not null:
`node.left?.let(nodes::add)`. This doesn't even require an explicit null check.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, i appreciate it! 
Should i add the node.left.let(nodes::add) instead of the node.left or after the left+right note? im very new at node-coding.

Comment: @PandaPacker I'll break the line down for you, so you can decide for yourself: The `?.` part means "only call this if the receiver (`node.left` in this case) is not `null`". And `let(nodes:add)` is simply shorthand for `let { leftNode -> nodes.add(leftNode) }`.

Answer (score -1):

```
    node.left?.let{
        nodes.add(it)
    }

    node.right?.let{
        nodes.add(it)
    }
```