# How can I await multiple futures, at once, that are nested inside a map?

Tags: dart

I have a `Map<String, List<Future<Foo>>>` that I want to convert to a `Map<String, List<Foo>>` (wait for futures to finish). Currently, this is how I perform the operation:

```
// source contains values with an async operation; convert to a map
final futures = source.map(
  (k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.map((e) async => await e.asyncOperation())),
);

final json = {};

// works, but must wait for each entry to process
for (final kvp in futures.entries) {
  json[kvp.key] = await Future.wait(kvp.value);
}
```

This will block for every entry sublist, is there a way to generate the proper `Map<String, List<Foo>>` while at the same time awaiting *all* of the inner list futures?

I can do `await Future.wait(futures.values.flattened);`, but how would I reassign the results back to the proper map key?

Comment: I am failing to see the issue with the solution you have proposed yourself. `await` is not a blocking operation. All of the futures you have yet to await can be completed while you `await` for one earlier in the loop to complete. All in all it should only take about as long as however long the longest future ends up taking, it is not the combined length of time of all futures to complete since they are completing concurrently.

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, you do not have a `Map<String, List<Future<Foo>>>` but rather a `Map<String, Iterable<Future<Foo>>>`. This would prevent the futures from completing concurrently because the futures are being created lazily as you iterate to them in the loop. The futures later on in the loop cannot complete concurrently if they don't exist yet. If you change `MapEntry(k, v.map((e) async => await e.asyncOperation()))` to `MapEntry(k, [for (var e in v) e.asyncOperation()])`, then my above statement should hold true, since I assumed you were using a `Map<String, List<Future<Foo>>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason to complete all the futures immediately would be that they already exist, and if you don't await all of them immediately, one of them might complete with an (unhandled!) error, which is bad.

The standard provided way to wait for more than one future at a time is `Future.wait`, which takes an `Iterable<Future<X>>` and returns a `Future<List<X>>`.

That will directly help you with the individual lists, but then you'll have a `Future<List<Foo>>` per key in the map. You'll have to convert those to a list too.
So, maybe something like:

```dart
Future<Map<String, List<Foo>>> waitAll(
    Map<String, Iterable<Future<Foo>>> map) async =>
  Map.fromIterables(map.keys.toList(), await Future.wait(map.values.map(Future.wait));
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to call `Future.wait<Foo>` on each of the inner `List<Future<Foo>>`s.  Each of those will return a `Future<List<Foo>>`; collect those `Future`s into their own list, and then use `Future.wait` again on that.

As you mentioned, the tricky part is assigning to results to the desired locations.  You can use `Future.then` to register a completion callback for each of the `Future<List<Foo>>`s that assigns the resulting `List<Foo>` to the new `Map`.  This is one situation where mixing `Future.then` with `await` is a little bit more straightforward than using just `await`. ([It's still possible with `await`, but it's more awkward.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61106550/))

For example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

/// Randomized delays to test correctness.
final delays = <int>[for (var i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) i]..shuffle();

/// Returns `result` after a randomized delay.
Future<int> f(int result) async {
  var index = result - 1;
  assert(index >= 0);
  assert(index < delays.length);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: delays[result - 1]));
  return result;
}

var map = <String, List<Future<int>>>{
  'foo': [f(1), f(2), f(3)],
  'bar': [f(4), f(5), f(6)],
  'baz': [f(7), f(8), f(9)],
};

Future<void> main() async {
  var newMap = <String, List<int>>{};
    await Future.wait<void>([
    for (var key in map.keys)
      Future.wait<int>(map[key]!).then((list) => newMap[key] = list),
  ]);
  
  print(newMap); // Prints: {foo: [1, 2, 3], bar: [4, 5, 6], baz: [7, 8, 9]}
}
```

Note that the above does not guarantee that `newMap` preserves the order of keys in the `Map`.  If you care about that, then an easy way to preserve the key order is to pre-add them to the new `Map`:

```dart
var newMap = {for (var key in map.keys) key: <int>[]};
```

or alternatively, remove and re-add them in the desired order afterward:

```dart
for (var key in map.keys) {
  newMap[key] = newMap.remove(key)!;
}
```