# Using Future<List<T>> in Future.wait

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm fetching data from APIs in Flutter. The data come from a several APIs, so I'm using Future.wait to make it smoother. I've got this variable:

```
late List<Cast> castMembers;
```

and this function:

```
 Future<List<Cast>> getCast() async {
    List<Cast> members= [];
    // here is the logic of serialization etc...
    return members;
  }
```

and finally  a function with Future.wait:

```
Future<void> callApi() async{
await Future.wait([       
        getAdresses(),
        getCountries(),  
        getPrices(),
        castMembers=await getCast()
      ]);
}
```

In this way Im getting an error. If I put the `castMembers=await getCast()` before the `Future.wait` it works fine, but in this case the methods inside the `Future.wait` won't excecute while we are waitng for the `getCast()`.

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: use the value returned by `Future.wait` method, the docs say: "The value of the returned future will be a list of all the values that were produced in the order that the futures are provided by iterating futures"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `await` on a `Future<List<Cast>>` will produce a `List<Cast>`.  Therefore doing `await Future.wait([await getCast()]);` will try to call `Future.wait` with a non-`Future`, and that isn't allowed.

As @pskink mentioned, `Future.wait` returns a `List` of the returned values, which you could use:

```dart
Future<void> callApi() async {
  var results = await Future.wait([
    getAdresses(),
    getCountries(),
    getPrices(),
    getCast(),
  ]);

  castMembers = results.last as List<Cast>;
}
```

Presumably `getAdresses` (sic), `getCountries`, `getPrices`, and `getCast` all return different types, so `results` will be the nearest common base type (probably `Object` or `List<Object>`), and you will need an explicit downcast.  That's a bit ugly, and it's also slightly brittle since if you ever add new `Future`s to `Future.wait` call, you might need to adjust which element to access from `results`, and that would not be enforced at compile-time.

Alternatively, you can use the approaches that I described in [Dart Future.wait for multiple futures and get back results of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61105410/):

```dart
Future<void> callApi() async {
  await Future.wait([
    getAdresses(),
    getCountries(),
    getPrices(),
    getCast().then((members) => castMembers = members),
  ]);
}
```

which is one of the few cases where I'd use `Future.then`.  Or wrap the assignment in a separate function to use pure `async`-`await`:

```dart
Future<void> callApi() async {
  Future<void> initializeCastMembers() async {
    castMembers = await getCast();
  }

  await Future.wait([
    getAdresses(),
    getCountries(),
    getPrices(),
    initializeCastMembers(),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The should not have the field `castMembers` as a member in the array, because it is not a `Future`.

When you type `castMembers=await getCast()`, this evaluates `getCast()`, puts its value in `castMembers`, and adds this value to the list.

In other words, you should have:

```dart
class A {
  late List<Cast> castMembers;

  Future<void> callApi() async {
    await Future.wait([
      getAdresses(),
      getCountries(),
      getPrices(),
      getCast(),
    ]);
  }

  Future<List<Cast>> getCast() async {
    List<Cast> members = [];
    return members;
  }

  Future<String> getAdresses() async => '';

  Future<int> getCountries() async => 1;

  Future<List<double>> getPrices() async => List.of();
}

class Cast {}
```

instead of

```dart
await Future.wait([       
  getAdresses(),
  getCountries(),  
  getPrices(),
  castMembers=await getCast()
]);
```

If you want the initialize the variable, then do it separately:

```dart
castMembers = await getCast();
await Future.wait([
  getAdresses(),
  getCountries(),
  getPrices(),
]);
```

Comment: But in your code the castMembers will never initialized.

Comment: Then you have to `await` it separately, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

With Dart 3, you may do this:

```
final (_, _, _, castMembers) = await (
     getAddresses(),
     getCountries(),
     getPrices(),
     getCastMembers(),
).wait;
```

then you may update `_castMembers` with `_castMembers = castMembers;`