# I need to get list with an argument

Tags: android, list, kotlin, arguments, kotlin-null-safety

```
private fun getRadResultList() {
    safeLet(
        arguments?.getString("referenceVisitId"), arguments?.getString("facilityId")
    ) { referenceVisitId, facilityId ->
        viewModel.getRadResultsWithId(referenceVisitId, facilityId)
    }
}
```

This is my previous code. The number of arguments requested by the function is now one. How do I return the facilityId in getRadResults()

```
private fun getRadResultList() {
    safeLet(
         arguments?.getString("facilityId")
    ) {  facilityId ->
        viewModel.getRadResults( facilityId)
    }
}
```

This code is the latest version. getRadResult() function wants only the facilityId.

Comment: What is safeLet here? I assume this is a function which takes some nullable values and a lambda, and then executes that lambda if all values are non-null. But can you add the entire function(s) in the question for better understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `safeLet`is the function mentioned in [Multiple variable let in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513636/multiple-variable-let-in-kotlin)

The thing is, that function is only necessary when wanting to check multiple variables. With a single variable you can use the default `let`. So like:

```
private fun getRadResultList() {
    arguments?.getString("facilityId")?.let { facilityId ->
        viewModel.getRadResults( facilityId)
    }
}
```