# Does Kotlin Have Something Similar to Swift's Guard-Let

Tags: swift, kotlin, unwrap, optional-chaining

In Swift I can do the following which would 1- make sure that none of these properties are nil and 2- give me access to them safely unwrapped:

```
// user could be nil, and lat and lon are properties on the user object, they can also be nil. Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid is a firebase uid which could be nil too.
guard let user = post.user,
      let lat = user.lat,
      let lon = user.lon,
      let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
else {
    return
}

print("latitude: \(lat), longtitude: \(lon), uid: \(currentUID)") 
// I now have access to lat, lon, and the current user's uid.
```

Does Kotlin offer any similar form of optional chaining where if anything is nil it'll trigger `return` but if none are I'm granted access to the unwrapped properties?

Comment: This looks to me like what you’re asking about. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513636/multiple-variable-let-in-kotlin

Comment: Exactly what I'm asking. I glanced over the answers, including the accepted answer, it seems you have to create a custom function to achieve what I'm looking for and it's not natively built into Kotlin. That's fine though, I'll pick one of them. THANKS for the response!!!  :)

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's the same link Tenfour04 sent in the comments, thanks! I went with the **accepted answer** from that link. I left this question up here in case anyone from the Swift world comes along and reads this. They can refer to these comments for help. Cheers!!!