# kotlin, is there a better way to check multiple nullables

Tags: kotlin, nullable

In kotlin it could use `?.let` to only run the code block if the variable is not null. If there are multiple variables it could be done like:

```
v1?.let { value1 ->
    v2?.let { value2 ->
        doSomething(value1, value2)
    }
}
```

compare with

```
if (v1 != null && v2 != null){
    doSomething(v1, v2)
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What does "better" mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513636/multiple-variable-let-in-kotlin

Comment: If you use [`konad`](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad), it seems like you could do something like `::doSomething.curry().on(v1.maybe).on(v2.maybe).nullable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function, pass any number of elements to it. And inside to check null or not.

```
fun notNull(vararg args: Any?, action: () -> Unit) {
        when (args.filterNotNull().size) {
            args.size -> action()
        }
    }
```

Example:

```
 val a = 2
 val b = "1"
 val c = "test"

 notNull(a, b, c){
           // works only when all args are not null
        }
```

Comment: That function might read a little better if called `ifNotNull()`, or `ifNoneNull()`.

Comment: You would have to null-assert `!!` them inside the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
!listOf(a, b).contains(null)
```

Or

```
!listOf(a, b).any{ it == null}
```

But it doesn't look really good.

Comment: (Or, equivalently, `null !in listOf(a, b)`.)